# Add shortcode wordpress in my plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I made a wordpress plugin, in which I call a shortcode of another plugin (revslider) but it does not work (i use this code `<?php add_shortcode( $tag , $func ); ?>`) How can i fix this problem?
thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 1):

To use a shortcode within any php file in theme or plugin. You can use this syntax:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[your-shortcode-here]' );
```

Resource: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Edit as Per Jordan's suggestion new code will check that shortcode exists, before using that:

```
  if ( shortcode_exists( 'gallery' ) ) {
    echo do_shortcode( '[gallery]' );
  }
```

Comment: You should also check that the plugin is active before calling the shortcode

Comment: @JordanCauley you are right i update answer with that condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're aware of this but just in case. If your plugin is calling the other one from within the content of a page and not in the .php files then Wordpress doesn't support PHP embedded in the page.

TO get around this you need a plugin called "Insert PHP" so similar. This then allows PHP code to run from a page but replace your  tags with [insert_php] and [/insert_php] respectively.

Sorry if this doesn't answer your question, just a thought.

Comment: i need to display a div when home page is load how can i make this?

Comment: This is a really bad suggestion, there is no use case where it is reasonable to run php from inside content

Comment: Apologies my bad explanation, I more meant if the PHP was within the pages on wordpress or if it was a back end file. You can't code PHP in wordpress, but with a plugin you can, my point was if the plugin needed to be called from this area then you would need to use the [insert_php] function

Comment: @cris if you literally want a <div> area defined you can edit the HTML of a single page in Wordpress. If you need a code example let me know.